# how to store 1-D array in a Matrix by adding a new row in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I am applying Dijkstra on each node in python using spyder. I am getting the correct results too but I am unable to store the results (1-D arrays) into an nxn matrix by adding a row. I am storing the data obtained from Dijkstra in D_path variable but in variable explorer, it is giving me the type as NoneType Object. I am appending it with the row and appending the row with the matrix.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

 
class Graph():
 
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.V = vertices
        self.graph = [[0 for column in range(vertices)]
                      for row in range(vertices)]
 
    def printSolution(self, dist):
        print("Vertex tDistance from Source")
        for node in range(self.V):
            print(node, "t", dist[node])
 
    # A utility function to find the vertex with
    # minimum distance value, from the set of vertices
    # not yet included in shortest path tree
    def minDistance(self, dist, sptSet):
 
        # Initialize minimum distance for next node
        min = sys.maxsize
 
        # Search not nearest vertex not in the
        # shortest path tree
        for v in range(self.V):
            if dist[v] < min and sptSet[v] == False:
                min = dist[v]
                min_index = v
 
        return min_index
 
    # Funtion that implements Dijkstra's single source
    # shortest path algorithm for a graph represented
    # using adjacency matrix representation
    def dijkstra(self, src):
 
        dist = [sys.maxsize] * self.V
        dist[src] = 0
        sptSet = [False] * self.V
 
        for cout in range(self.V):
 
            # Pick the minimum distance vertex from
            # the set of vertices not yet processed.
            # u is always equal to src in first iteration
            u = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet)
 
            # Put the minimum distance vertex in the
            # shortest path tree
            sptSet[u] = True
 
            # Update dist value of the adjacent vertices
            # of the picked vertex only if the current
            # distance is greater than new distance and
            # the vertex in not in the shortest path tree
            for v in range(self.V):
                if self.graph[u][v] > 0 and sptSet[v] == False and dist[v] > dist[u] + self.graph[u][v]:
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + self.graph[u][v]
 
        self.printSolution(dist)
 
 
# Driver program
g = Graph(9)
g.graph = [[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
           [4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0],
           [0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
           [0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6],
           [8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7],
           [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0]
           ]
#D_path = list()

matrix=[] #define empty matrix
for i in range(9): #total row is 3
    row=[] 
    D_path = g.dijkstra(i)
    row.append(D_path) #adding 0 value for each column for this row
    matrix.append(row) #add fully defined column into the row
print (matrix)
```

Comment: well. your dijkstra method on Graph class not return anything. Should add a return. Also, you could use yield keyword and implement generator to make your code more efficient. BUt adding return should make it work.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho thank you so much it started working i was doing it the wrong way by not returning anything thank you so much